# Custom Element Reference Tags

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, elementtype, reference-tags

I have created a custom element type and cant get the reference tags to parse correctly, I've set the refHandle and the action to copy reference tag which seems to be correct format when I copy a reference tag.

If I try to parse that in a template it doesn't work, it just stays in the reference format {refHandle:identifier}, I have the syntax correct because it works with entries and other base element types.

Am I missing something from my element type? I can't see anything from the docs or from looking through the craft commerce plugin as a guide.